# CSS margins not working

Tags: html, css

take a look at this:

[image]

Here is my css:

```
    <style>
        .backups {
            border-radius: 2px;
            border: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
            padding: 3%;
            display: inline-block;
            width: 100%;
            margin-right: 5px;
            height: 485px;
            margin: 0px;
        }
        .backups_header {
            background-color: #E7E7E7;
        }
    </style>
```

Why are margins not working?

I want the "backups_header" to be flush with the top of the backups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And they are, but the font probably doesn't fill its entire height. There is a bit of spacing around a the letters that make it look like a margin of about two pixels. If you select it, the highlight will reveil the actual line height.

There is no proper way to fix this, because it can be different for each font and even slightly differ on each machine (especially different OS'es), but your best bet would be to set a `line-height` and tweak it until it is just right.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason is that you are again changing the margins below. write margin:0px above!

```
`<style>
    .backups {
        border-radius: 2px;
        border: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
        padding: 3%;
        margin: 0px;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100%;
        margin-right: 5px;
        height: 485px;
        
    }
    .backups_header {
        background-color: #E7E7E7;
    }
   </style>`
```